# How can I make my inserted images in flash obey my layer order?

Tags: flash, actionscript, layer

So I am inserting images dynamically into Flash with actionscript; that's no problem.
However I want to set the image to appear underneath my buttons layer, because when I insert the image it covers up all buttons.

I've tried "addChildIndex(myLoader, 0)" but it seems to place the image behind everything and incrementing the index number has the same effect.

I've placed my actionsript layer below the buttons layer thinking that would work, but of course it isn't that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone figured out a fix for me; instead of "addChildIndex(myLoader, #)" change the number for "numChildren -#".  It pushes the image back behind each object.. Correct me if I'm wrong on its function, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
addChildAt(myLoader, getChildIndex(yourDisplayObject));
```

where "yourDisplayObject" is the Display Object you want the loader to appear behind (a button in your case im guessing)

This will add myLoader at the 'depth' that yourDisplayObject is occupying and shift yourDisplayObject (and any other objects in front of it) up one level/depth.